# Headphones you can't blow out

Tags: headphones

So I have gone through a lot of cheapo headphones because the headphones blow out.
Are there headphones that can't be blown out?

I would like them to fit in a pocket and not be like the big ones that go on your head.  I'm using the earbuds with an android phone.

EDIT: So I determined the 3.5mm was wearing out on the cheap headphones I was buying.

Comment: Could you provide some more details about the headphones? E.g.: on the ear vs. over the ear, budget, wired or wireless, impedance and what you mean by "blown out". It helps myself and others find a more suitable recommendation. :)

Comment: Sounds to me like you are looking for earbuds.  Here's a little tip.  If you are constantly ruining earbuds, you are listening to music way too loud.  You are causing long term damage to your hearing.   If you find you constantly need to increase volume, you likely already have hearing damage.  Try to lay off the high decibel levels for a while.  I will not be posting any recommendations, as I believe doing so will be detrimental to your well being.

Comment: You need to compare the power output specs of the sound card or device and the input specs. for the earphones. My guess would be that "cheapo" means "low power" or "low quality". At least for a recommendation you need to state the device you are using them with.

Comment: @0-60FPS I believe it is caused from playing the music at maximum volume.  Yes I'm looking for earbuds.

Comment: I wish there were a "off-topic due to potential damage to users health or safety" vote to close reason *sigh*

Comment: yeah, you're gonna need to turn the music down @William. I'd also recommend over-ear headphones rather than earbuds, as they carry less risk of damaging your hearing.

Comment: @ArtOfCode  Not to mention they have better sound quality, and insulate against outside noise, which lowers the need to have music on blast in the first place.

Comment: If this was asking for OE headphones, I'd recommend mine - Sony noise-cancelling things. They're brilliant.

Comment: Yes I have never had problems with over the ear headphones just earbuds and blow out.

Comment: You're unlikely to blow out headphones with a phone, even with the most sensitive headphones. Your eardrums on the other hand... cheapo headphones are often badly made, and you might be damaging it in other ways.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  Which is why i doubt he has "blown out" earbuds, but more like just ruined the bass on low end earbuds.    Personally, I cannot stand earbuds, I prefer over the ear cans.

Comment: I prefer cans too. Impractical for outdoor use. My outside earbuds do isolate well though.

Comment: @NZKshatriya they no longer output sound and they blow out at separate times.   Right 1st then left earbud.

Comment: @William   First, I would advise you not go for the bargain bin earphones, and second I would try not having the volume set at anything past 75%.  Remember, you get what you pay for.  If you buy $15 earphones, don't expect Bose or Klipsch qualiity.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  I use my Skullcandy HESH 2.0's everywhere lol, don't care if I look strange or not, I want my sound lol.   And I want a freaking wire, cannot stand wireless.

Comment: @NZKshatriya are apple headphones cheap?

Comment: @William  Well, if they are the basic, shipped with the device type earbuds, then yes.   Remember, Apple is a phone/computer company, not an audio equipment company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:  No, there are no headphones(over the ear, on the ear, earbuds) in existence that cannot be: Blown out, have their speaker components damaged over time from being played at maximum output.

The same goes for high end speaker systems.  Running a speaker system at full blast puts stress on all components, which will lead to parts needing to be replaced.